# Javascript regex for address

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I would like to make a way wherein if the user inputs his/her address in the input field and clicks submit my app will process it and store the address into the specific fields. For example:

User Address Input:
135 Lot 10 Block 20 Dewmond Street Sta Rosa Village 6 Calamba Laguna 4027 Philippines

What I want:

```
Unit: 135 Lot 10 Block 20
Street: Dewmond Street
Compound: Sta Rosa Village 6
City: Calamba
Province: Laguna
Zip: 4027
Country: Philippines
```

Comment: Before what you want, you should always put what your tried

Comment: There's no way to do this (reliably) with regex, or anything else for that matter.

Comment: I would suggest using Google Place api. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Comment: Look into Right Fielder http://www.melissadata.com/dqt/rightfielder.htm

Answer (score 0):

It can be very VERY hard (read "impossible" :P) achieve what you want using regular expressions. I highly suggest you to use [Google Place Autocomplete API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform). It's very easy to use, reliable, and free.

[Here](https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/) some interesting facts about addresses and why the address parsing it's not an easy task.

Comment: Google Place Autocomplete API sound kinda interesting. Thanks BTW :)